# Character frequency based string search

Tags: python, string, list, algorithm, search

I am curious about string search algorithms, and came up with a technique based on character usage frequencies. My naive logic is as follows:

If looking for `"axe"` in some string, there's no point getting excited when you bump into an `"a"`, but definitely get excited if you bump into an `"x"` since the usage of `"x"` is far lower than that of `"a"`.

So I decided to try and implement this idea. The code breaks a couple of raw algorithm rules (makes use of `list.index`), but not to the point where it impacts the code's performance noticeably and there would be appropriate work-arounds that I can't be bothered investigating. Here it is:

```py
def algorithm(text, pattern):
    freqs = {'e' : 12.0,
    't' : 9.10,
    'a' : 8.12,
    'o' : 7.68,
    'i' : 7.31,
    'n' : 6.95,
    's' : 6.28,
    'r' : 6.02,
    'h' : 5.92,
    'd' : 4.32,
    'l' : 3.98,
    'u' : 2.88,
    'c' : 2.71,
    'm' : 2.61,
    'f' : 2.30,
    'y' : 2.11,
    'w' : 2.09,
    'g' : 2.03,
    'p' : 1.82,
    'b' : 1.49,
    'v' : 1.11,
    'k' : 0.69,
    'x' : 0.17,
    'q' : 0.11,
    'j' : 0.10,
    'z' : 0.07 }

    letters = list(freqs.keys())

    pattern_len = len(pattern)
    ranks = sorted([(letters.index(pattern[i]), i) for i in range(pattern_len)], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    # This is the key outcome of preprocessing. It orders the indices of pattern's characters from least frequent, to most frequent, and in the case of duplicates, a secondary sort from rightmost occurrence to left.
    rep = [e[1] for e in sorted(ranks, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)]

    reference_index = 0

    algstart = time.time()
    for i in range(len(text)):
        # This is a very important line. Essentially, it allows me to shift the sequence forward by a step greater than 1 and based on the character that has been shifted to, find the offset index of where I hope the least frequent character to appear in the text.
        z = i - reference_index

        if text[z] == pattern[rep[0]]:

            for j in range(1, pattern_len):
                text_char = text[z - rep[0] + rep[j]]

                # Char mismatch, so shift to match or beginning of substring
                if text_char != pattern[rep[j]]:
                    if text_char in pattern:
                        shift_distance = rep[j] - (pattern.index(text_char) + 1)
                    else:
                        shift_distance = rep[j]

                    i += shift_distance
                    reference_index = shift_distance
                    break

                # Found it!
                if j == pattern_len - 1:
                    local_vars = list(locals().items())
                    size = sum([sys.getsizeof(obj) for var, obj in local_vars if var != "text"])
                    print(f"My amended alg found the pattern at index {z - rep[0]} in {time.time() - algstart}ms using {size}b of memory!!")
                    return
```

I do have another solution that doesn't make use of `list.index` or `in`, but it is far less readable and the time difference is negligible.

In my brief testing using a text file of Alice in Wonderland, this algorithm performed around 2x as good as KMP, but Boyer-Moore still beat it by >3x. However, with words such as `"queen"`, it outperformed both algorithms (albeit Boyer-Moore only slightly). Obviously the algorithm requires an uneven distribution of character frequencies. Also, the frequency data was just pulled off the internet, but I am sure that I could moderately improve the speed if I collected frequencies from the actual text.

Does anyone have any suggestions for improving the speed of this algorithm? Is there any similar algorithm that I should look into? Thanks!

Comment: .. is it faster than a native Python string search?

Comment: Hard to say since the inbuilt `if a in b` runs in C or CPython so it’s hard to compare

Comment: Then you have nothing to compare with, right? It is an interesting idea, but to compare you will need to compete with compiled C (which typically uses a very efficient optimization of the most straightforward brute force method). Or, write (or search for) current implementations of search algorithms in Python.

Comment: I have written both KMP and Boyer-Moore implementations in Python, as discussed in the post. So I’d argue that they are two bounding points of comparison